# Error 65535 from CommDlgExtendedError after calling GetFileSaveName

Tags: winapi

So, I'm calling GetFileSaveName from some C code. The C code is called from PowerBuilder, but I really don't think that is relevant.

On just one user's computer currently (Windows 10, updates done), it returns 0, then CommDlgExtendedError return 65535 (CDERR_DIALOGFAILURE), which the docs say means "The dialog box could not be created. The common dialog box function's call to the DialogBox function failed. For example, this error occurs if the common dialog box call specifies an invalid window handle."

I know that the common dialogs aren't completely broken on her PC - I can pull up a File Open or Save dialog in Notepad, for instance.

I had a bug in my code giving the same error number in the past, where in the OPENFILENAME structure I passed in to GetOpenFileName I had set the hWndOwner variable to a handle to a window that no longer exists, but in this case it is being set to 0, so that's not the problem.

The same code is working for thousands of other users of our software! Any bright ideas what could be going on? Thanks.

OK, people have asked me to post my code initializing the OpenFileName structure. It's PowerScript (PowerBuilder's coding language) but should be pretty comprehensible).

```
OPENFILENAME iOFN
CONSTANT long CHARSIZE = 2
aul_flags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY + OFN_EXPLORER + 
    OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST+ OFN_NOCHANGEDIR + OFN_DONTADDTORECENT

RtlZeroMemory(iOFN, ll_sizeof)

// initialize structure
iOFN.lStructSize = ll_sizeof
iOFN.nFilterIndex = 1
iOFN.nMaxFile = MAX_LENGTH
iOFN.hWndOwner = il_hWnd
iOFN.Flags = aul_flags + OFN_ENABLESIZING /* needed when using hook procedure */

// allocate memory and copy title
ll_length = Len(as_title) * CHARSIZE
iOFN.lpstrTitle = LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, ll_length + 2)
RtlMoveMemory(iOFN.lpstrTitle, as_title, ll_length)

// allocate memory and copy filter
this.of_Parse(",", as_filter, ls_filter)
li_max = UpperBound(ls_filter) /* count of 1-based array elements */
For li_cnt = 1 To li_max
    ll_length = this.of_StringToChar(Trim(ls_filter[li_cnt]), lc_filter)
Next
ll_length = UpperBound(lc_filter) * CHARSIZE
iOFN.lpstrFilter = LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, ll_length)
RtlMoveMemory(iOFN.lpstrFilter, lc_filter, ll_length)

// allocate memory and copy default extension (if given)
If as_extension <> "" Then
    ll_length = Len(as_extension) * CHARSIZE
    iOFN.lpstrDefExt = LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, ll_length)
    RtlMoveMemory(iOFN.lpstrDefExt, as_extension, ll_length)
End If

// allocate memory and copy initialdir (if given)
If as_initdir <> "" Then
    ll_length = Len(as_initdir) * CHARSIZE
    iOFN.lpstrInitialDir = LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, ll_length)
    RtlMoveMemory(iOFN.lpstrInitialDir, as_initdir, ll_length)
End If

// allocate memory for returned data
lc_pathname = Space(MAX_LENGTH)
iOFN.nMaxFile = MAX_LENGTH
iOFN.lpstrFile = LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, MAX_LENGTH)
If as_initialfile <> "" Then
    ll_length = Len(as_initialfile) * CHARSIZE
    RtlMoveMemory(iOFN.lpstrFile, as_initialfile, ll_length)
End If

// display dialog box
lb_return = GetOpenFileName(iOFN)
```

Comment: Can you show your actual code? Maybe there is another bug in it you are not seeing, that only manifests on this one PC.  Do you hook the dialog for anything?

Comment: It's a lot of code, and some of it is in PowerBuilder and some in C, so it could be a bit hard to read. I have an option of hooking the dialog but it's not active in this instance.

Comment: I was referring only to your `GetSaveFileName()` code that is failing, not your whole app code. In any case, have you considered simply not using `Get(Open|Save)FileName()` anymore? They have been deprecated since Windows Vista, you should be using `IFile(Open|Save)Dialog` nowadays. Do you have a similar failure with that API?

Comment: You should at least show `OPENFILENAME` initialization code.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to check if there is any problem with the [OPENFILENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea) parameter configuration. There are many parameters in OPENFILENAME that need to be configured before GetSaveFileName can be used. Maybe there is something wrong.

```
TCHAR szFilename[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");
 BOOL bResult = FALSE;
 DWORD dwError = NOERROR;
 OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };

 ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
 ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All Files\0*.*\0\0");
 ofn.lpstrFile = szFilename;
 ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
 ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER |
   OFN_ENABLEHOOK |
   OFN_HIDEREADONLY |
   OFN_NOCHANGEDIR |
   OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;

 bResult = GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
 if (bResult == FALSE)
 {
     dwError = CommDlgExtendedError();
     return dwError;
 }
```

Comment: *"Maybe there is something wrong."* is not an answer.

Comment: But maybe OP forgot to initialize `OPENFILENAME` eg `OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };` and has incostistent OPENFILENAME state.

Comment: Yes, maybe. And if you are not sure then the comments are the right place to ask for clarification.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is working for thousands of users, with one exception, all with the same code. So I suspect it's something pretty subtle. I'm going to be really busy for a couple of days but will try to post my code as soon as I can.

Comment: I'd like to comment, but my reputation won't let me. Thank you for your criticism. I will try harder to answer the questions well.